# How to trigger Click event after associated interface has loaded for the first time only?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I want to make sure that a certain interface is loaded and displayed before i can trigger a click event on a button contained in that interface.

I am creating the interface using the following code :

```
   var mainV2 = Ext.create('widget.main', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            hideMode: 'visibility',
           //Update
            listeners: {
              afterrender: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('#somebutton').fireEvent('click');
                        }
                 }
        });

        mainV2.show();
```

And firing the event right under the mentioned code

```
Ext.getCmp('#idcheckItem').fireEvent('click');
```

But it seems that the fireEvent is not affecting the button listener's. I was thinking because the call should be synchronous.

My question is how to make sure the `mainV2` has loaded before firing the click event on the button only when `mainV2` is called and displayed for the first time  ?

Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an afterRender method in the panels controller.

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aku)

This fiddle fires a buttons click event after the window is rendered.
Be sure to put the afterRender method in the controller.  I ran into some trouble when putting it directly on the panel.

Comment: Is it possible to make a listener afterRender on the mainV2 panel ?

Comment: Please see EDIT : i want the event to fire only for the first time the panel is displayed.

Comment: afterRender is on the component in the classic toolkit and widget in the modern toolkit. So anything that extends these methods you can create the afterRender method.  The afterRender is only called once so the event will only be fired once.

Comment: I don't quiet understand is it possible to add afterRender as a listener (as shown in my edit) instead of creating a method in the controller as you mentioned ?

Comment: There is no afterrender event on container, so I don't think that will work. With that said, after the component is rendered, this method is called by the framework.  So it is like an afterRender event, i guess. I don't understand why what I suggested would not work.  Can you put your code in a fiddle and show me what it is not doing?

Comment: nothing wrong with your code except i want to decouple the controller from the view : so the suggested method afterrender in my case should be defined in the controller seperately and not using the controller config as you did, so what i want is a bit different from what you wrote

Comment: Your reference method to get the button didn't work either, i had to do it with itemId then catch the button using itemId="someid" in Query method. thanks and also i used the above edited solution of mine to get this working. so thanks anyways

Comment: It works because it is working in the fiddle.  If you don't have a controller then the findReference will not work.  I can't say why or why not it is working for you without a fiddle example.  The view and the controller are designed to work together.... not sure why or even how you would decouple them.

Comment: They are, but you are implementing the afterrender method in view by specifying a config (which is `controller : {...}`). i have defined a file for the view (containing `MyApp.view.Main`) and another file (containing the associated controller) : that's what i meant by 'decoupling'. But for selecting using this syntax : `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("window[reference=window1]")[0];` that didn't work (don't know why btw) : so i used itemId and then the following syntax : `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("[itemId=button1]")[0];` and then as shown in my above code used a listener. Thanks anyway Mark !